# Java: Minimizing a Jframe Window without causing the program to run again

Tags: java, swing

My program uses a Jframe, whenever I minimize the window and bring it back up, the program runs itself again. How can I cause it to not do this when minimized?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class AB extends Component {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Random r = new Random();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(100), 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        f.setSize(dim.width, dim.height);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        f.add(new AB());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's guess...you have a WindowListener monitoring the visibility state? You have ContainerListerner listening for some state change in the content pane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I made a different SWAG, but your's is good too. Who knows given the sparse details presented.

Comment: Thanks for posting code. Yep, I was right. Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: you have program logic present in your `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method override. If so, get the logic out of these methods, because as you're finding out, you do not have full control over when or even if they are called. The logic belongs elsewhere, perhaps in a Swing Timer, hard to say without code or a more detailed question.

If this doesn't help, then you'll need to show us the bugs in your code by creating and posting a [minimal, runnable, example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as tell us more of the details of your program and its misbehavior.

---

After looking at your code, I see that my assumption/guess was correct: you are selecting your random numbers inside of the paint method, and so they will change with each repaint. You will want to

- Create a class that extends JPanel.
- Create your random numbers in this class's **constructor**, and use the random numbers to set class instance fields.
- Override this class's `paintComponent` method
- Don't forget to call the super's `paintComponent` method inside this method.
- Use the numbers generated in the constructor in the `paintComponent` method override to draw your rectangle.
- Place your JPanel into a JFrame.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RandomRect extends JPanel {
   private static final int MAX_INT = 100;
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.black;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private int randomX;
   private int randomY;

   public RandomRect() {
      randomX = random.nextInt(MAX_INT);
      randomY = random.nextInt(MAX_INT);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
      g.fillRect(randomX, randomY, MAX_INT, MAX_INT);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RandomRect");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new RandomRect());
      //frame.pack();
      // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I love playing these guessing games :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer LOL. I initially posted this as a comment but changed it to an answer because I just have a feeling about it...